# Can you make for loops in one line in c#?

Tags: c#

In python, you can write for loops in one line such as:

```
myList = [print(x) for x in range(10)]
```

Can you do something similar in c#?

Comment: I mean, anything in C# can technically be inline. If you're looking for a simplified syntax, there isn't really one.  `List`s have a `ForEach` method you can use, but I do not recommend this over a normal foreach loop. It can get a lot messier really quickly. You could also use linq if you're looking to compile a list, but it's not meant to be used as an inline foreach loop for printing things like you're doing in your example.

Comment: https://www.goodreads.com/quotes/6341736-any-fool-can-write-code-that-a-computer-can-understand

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes, if there is only one statement inside the loop, you can put it on the same line:

```cs
foreach (var x in Enumerable.Range(0, 10)) Console.WriteLine(x);
```

Answer (score 6):

Yes, you can:

```
var myList = from x in Enumerable.Range(0, 10) select x;
```

The term in Python is *list comprehension*. I don't think it has a special name in C#, except the general concept called LINQ.

As for your original code

```
myList = [print(x) for x in range(10)]
```

The content of `myList` like that will be `[None, None, None, None, None, None, None, None, None, None]` because `print()` does not return anything. I guess that's not intended. If you really want that, you can go with

```
var myList = Enumerable.Range(0, 10).Select<int,object>(x=>{Console.WriteLine(x); return null; });
```

Be aware that LINQ has lazy evaluation, so the Console output may not appear until you use the list, unlike Python, which if I recall correctly prints right away.

Answer (score 1):

While I don't really recommend it, a `List` has a `ForEach` method, which lets you execute an action on each element. I don't recommend this because LINQ is intended for actions that don't cause side effects. ForEach can cause side effects.

```
Enumerable.Range(0, 10).ToList().ForEach(x => Console.WriteLine(x));

// or slightly shorter without the lambda, same thing
Enumerable.Range(0, 10).ToList().ForEach(Console.WriteLine);
```

I'd much rather go with a foreach loop. Linq's not the best when it comes to something other than *querying* data.

Answer (score 0):

```
var list = Enumerable.Range(0,10).Select(i=>{Console.WriteLine(i); return i; });
```